# 0% Code Coverage in Production with Quick Deploy

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

Just realized an issue with some of my code coverage. I've been using Quick Deploy quite a lot lately and haven't seemed to have any issues -- my triggers have good code coverage in the sandbox (85-100%) and pass the validation deploy, so I use Quick Deploy and everything's great.

Thing is, I just noticed that most of the triggers I've deployed this way are showing 0% code coverage in production. They show full code coverage in the sandbox, and passed totally fine -- so I think the only issue has to be with the Quick Deploy process.

Has anyone else had this problem? I'm unsure if it's a Quick Deploy bug, or a failure on my part. Wanted to ask around before I create a case.

Thanks!

Comment: What results you get after when you "Run All Test" in production?

Comment: I assume the tests that cover the triggers in the Sandbox are a) in production already or b) in the deployment set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STEPS:

1) You have to re-compile all the classes/triggers - "**Compile all Classes**" link on Apex Classes page. (i.e.) You need to make sure "**Is Valid**" check box on Classes and Triggers pages to be checked/enabled.

2) You need to execute "**Run All Tests**" to get the code coverage for the components back.

**UPDATE:**

Please clear the Test Data/ Test Execution History before proceeding to the steps listed above. Thanks @Enreeco

Comment: I whould also suggest a Setup > Apex Test Execution > View Test History > Clear Test Data

Comment: Yes.  This should be the first step before what I listed. Thanks @Enreeco . Let me update the main answer with this information, as it gets the broader audience.

Comment: Perfect, sorry for the delay but thank you Vignex!

Answer (score 0):

This is the random behavior from Salesforce. Though if we compile all classes still its not working.

Please suggest some more options.